# Website hosted on LAN not accessible

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver

I have a webserver setup on a Raspberry PI within my LAN along with a free domain with A records pointing to my IP, I can access the website from my phone using 4G but the only way I can access my website on my LAN is by going to the internal IP of my Raspberry PI. Is there any way round this?

Comment: You have to enable port forwarding in your router.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the raspberry pi's hostname. you can check the pi's hostname by entering "cat /etc/hostname" in the command line (assuming you use a linux distro). remove the quotes. if the primary primary dns for your network is the router then you can enter http://hostname and it should take you to your server.